# Best way to prevent looping using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm relatively new to D3, and I'm wondering about the best way to prevent code like this. Often I rarely see people loop in D3.js. However I haven't quite yet understood why they don't have to. Given this code I have is it necessary to loop? or is there a way to prevent looping like so? have the following code snippet:

```
var tickPath = svg.selectAll('.tickPath')
    .data(tickValues)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr('class', 'tickPath')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      var tickArray = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < numBars; i++) tickArray.push({c : d});
      return area(tickArray);
    })
    .style('fill', (d) => color(d))
    .style('stroke', (d, i) => (i === 0) ? 'black' : '#5e5e5e')
    .style('stroke-width', (d, i) => (i === 0) ? '1px' : '.5px');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see code like yours because people usually use the [axis component](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) instead of building one from scratch.

Another thing is that [selections](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Selections) encapsulate looping. From d3's docs:

> You won't generally need to use for loops or recursive functions to modify the document with D3. That's because you operate on entire selections at once, rather than looping over individual elements. However, you can still loop over elements manually if you wish.

However, a SVG path is a single element so a d3 selection won't help to avoid/hide looping in your case.

Comment: this is for a radarchart so straight lines wouldn't work? Not sure

Comment: Heres a link to the code im looking at: http://bl.ocks.org/Saintat1/ec8b09eb1ee78ca638b6135cd3c942db

Comment: Right! The axis component is good for line or bar charts. It wouldn't work in your case.

Comment: @jamestwiggle See my updated answer. I added a few words about selections and why they don't help in your case.